# How to map List<String> where each string is a comma separated strings to List<String> split on commas joined?

Tags: java, java-stream

tags -- `["tag1", "tag2, tag3"]`

expected output -- `["tag1","tag2","tag3"]`

Current code:

```
List<String> tagsProcessed = new ArrayList<>();
for(String t : tags) {
    tagsProcessed.addAll(Stream.of(t.split(",")).map(String::trim).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

How to rewrite it with streams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one solution of many:

```
var delimiter = Pattern.compile(",");
tags.stream()
    .flatMap(delimiter::splitAsStream)
    .map(String::trim)
    .forEach(tagsProcessed::add);
```

---

or, *avoiding* (hiding!) the `trim` call (but without removing white spaces at start and end of input strings):

```
var delimiter = Pattern.compile("\\s*,\\s*");
tags.stream()
    .flatMap(delimiter::splitAsStream)
    .forEach(tagsProcessed::add);
```

<sup>I prefer first one, clearly showing the call to `trim`</sup>

---

all the above can also be changed to (directly) use the result of `Collectors.toList()`, but beware of kind of returned `List`. From documentation:

> There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned; if more control over the returned List is required, use toCollection(Supplier).

Using it with `addAll` is not a problem (but similar to using `forEach` as in above code); also not a problem if the returned list is not being changed.

Comment: i was doing flatMap(t -> t.split(",")) directly, and that gives Stream<String[]> i think. splitAsStream is magical. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `flatMap`, which can map one element to any number of elements, represented as a stream. In this case, we map each tag to the array of tags produced by `split`.

```
List<String> tagsProcessed = tags.stream()
    .flatMap(tag -> Arrays.stream(tag.split(", ")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
List<String> tagsProcessed = tags.stream()
        .map(s -> s.trim().split(",\\s*"))
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> tags = Arrays.asList("1 ,2   ,3 ,4  ", "5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ", "  9,  10");
List<String> tagsProcessed =
    tags.stream() //Stream the list of String as is
        .flatMap(tag -> Arrays.stream(tag.split(","))) // flatMap to avoid Stream<Stream<String>>, this produces Stream<String>
        .map(String::trim) //trim as in requirement
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```